# current_timestamp gives different time from now() in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, timestamp

In my database, registration_time is set to `current_timestamp`. But it is 7 hours early. How can I correct it?

Comment: Have you checked what the time is set to on the server?

Answer (score 0):

you actual mysql time is different then you php

to check

```
The current values of the global and client-specific time zones can be retrieved like this: 
mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

To set it for the current session, do:

```
SET time_zone = timezonename;
```

Also you can find detail about timezone set at this [link](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/databases/how-to-change-mysql-server-time-zone)